# Finding a formula for the sequence $10, \,110,\,1110,\,11110,\dotsc$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How can I find a formula for the sequence

$$10,\,110,\,1110,\, 11110,\dotsc$$

to make it ready for summation?

Comment: $a_n=\sum \limits_{k=1}^n\left(10^k\right)$

Comment: This is important to me sum 9/(10(10^n-1))=0.110918190....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we call your numbers $a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots$, then 
$$a_n=(10)\left(\frac{10^n-1}{9}\right).$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  at each step you are adding a power of $10$.  That should make it easy to build a summation.  Otherwise it is the sum of a finite geometric series.

Answer (score 2):

The sequence is defined by
$$u_0=0,\quad u_n=10^n+u_{n-1}\ \forall n\ge1$$

so by telescoping and summing the geometric sequence we find
$$u_n=\sum_{k=1}^n u_k-u_{k-1}=\sum_{k=1}^n10^k=10\frac{10^n-1}{10-1}$$