# Alernative way of solving summation $5+55+555+\ldots$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, arithmetic-progressions, geometric-progressions

### Question

> Find the summation for the series-:
> $$5+55+555+5555+...$$

I know it is a duplicate of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1024158/how-to-find-a-general-sum-formula-for-the-series-5555555555/1024191#1024191), but still, I am posting this because i was thinking of solving another way due to which I got stuck in another series.

### My Attempt

$S=5+55+555+5555....$

$2*S=10+110+1110+11110....$

$=10*(1+11+111+1111+...)$

$=\frac{10}{9}*(9+99+999+9999+...)$

$=\frac{10}{9}*((10-1)+(10^{2}-1)+(10^{3}-1)+(10^{4}-1)+...)$

$=\frac{10}{9}*(10*\frac{10^{n}-1}{10-1}-n)$

$=\frac{10}{9}*(\frac{10^{n+1}-10}{9}-n)$

$$S=\frac{5}{9}*(\frac{10^{n+1}-10}{9}-n)$$

So i think i got my answer.But i have doubt in summation of series-:

$S=10+110+1110+11110....$

I got summation (from above ) as-:
$=\frac{10}{9}*(\frac{10^{n+1}-10}{9}-n)$

But [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/565750/finding-a-formula-for-the-sequence-10-110-1110-11110-dotsc) , it is different .Which one is correct? I am stuck .
Please help me out !

Comment: Your answer is correct. The second question you linked to only has answers that give you the $n^{th}$ term of the sequence $10, 110, \ldots$